# Mocking base class in a unit test for Angular 2

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a unit test to see if the base class method gets called

Here is the base class

```
export abstract class Animal{
   protected eatFood() {
      console.log("EAT FOOD!")
   }
}
```

Here is the class I want to test

```
export class Monkey extends Animal {
   onHungry(){
      this.eatFood();
   }
}
```

Here is the test

```
class MockAnimal {
  public eatFood() { 
    console.log("EAT MOCKED FOOD!");
  }
}

describe('Monkey', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       declarations:[Monkey],
       providers: [
         { provide: Animal, useClass: MockAnimal }
       ]
    }
  });

  it('eat food when hungry', fakeAsync(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Monkey);
    spyOn(fixture, 'eatFood');
    fixture.componentInstance.onHungry();
    expect(fixture.eatFood).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
}
```

I can't get the unit test to run this `MockAnimal` class. Is this how to test it?

Comment: spy on fixture.componentInstance, not the fixture. fixture has no method eatFood

Comment: thanks @peeskillet That didnt work. How do I execute eatFood in the MockAnimal class instead of the actual Animal class?

Answer (score 0):

The TestBed is used to test components and as in a normal NgModule you define declarations, imports, providers, ... But what you want to test is a simple class. In the test you have to initialize it manually:

```
describe('Monkey', () => {
  it('eats if hungry', () => {
    const monkey = new Monkey();
    // spying will only work if 'eatFood' is public
    const eatFoodSpy = spyOn(monkey, 'eatFood');

    monkey.onHungry();

    expect(eatFoodSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: This basically changes the `eatFood` method on the specific instance of `Monkey`, `monkey`. It doesn't do anything for `Animal`, which is what the question is about. If you changed it to `spyOn(Animal.prototype, 'eatFood').and.callFake(() => console.log('EAT FAKE FOOD'));`, it might work.

Comment: Hmm... as Monkey extends Animal, I do not see any advantage by spying on the Animal prototype. The more important point is: if you want to spy a function, it has to be public. If it is protected as in the example, you cannot spy it. (Unless you do some hacks.)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this, that will mock your call.

```
  it('eat food when hungry', fakeAsync(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Monkey);
    fixture.componentInstance['eatFood'] = jasmine.createSpy('eatFood');
    fixture.componentInstance.onHungry();
    expect(fixture.eatFood).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```